# Defining distance between points in meters

Tags: postgis, srid, st-distance

I want to calculate the distance in meters between two points but I am getting 
an obscene result `5497980.47338251`

Here is the query I made:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_SeTSRID(ST_MakePoint(6761331.47, 2873883.72), 2154), 
                   ST_SeTSRID(ST_MakePoint(2873464.28, 6761335.07), 2154)),
       ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(6761331.47, 2873883.72), 
                   ST_MakePoint(2873464.28, 6761335.07))
```

The coordinates are in the `2154` SRID.

What should I do to get a good result? I tried with the 4326 SRID and the appropriate coordinates and got a wrong answer as well.

Comment: I think you mixed x and y in one of the `ST_MakePoint`, the result should be meters!

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned by @ThingumaBob playing around with coordinates order will give better output

```sql
SELECT ST_Distance(
                   ST_SeTSRID(ST_MakePoint(6761331.47, 2873883.72), 2154),
                   ST_SeTSRID(ST_MakePoint(6761335.07, 2873464.28), 2154)
                   ) AS dist
```

`dist = 419.4554488862289` meters, [EPSG:2154](https://epsg.io/2154).